# Cefsharp : problem with the Reqest Context of the General Usage page

Tags: cefsharp, requestcontext

I have some problems, to change user profile with cefsharp 71.0.2.
All is working good with an user1.
To change users, the [General Usage Wiki page](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation) gives me the solution.
But the 3rd line of this code

```
    var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = cachePath2 };
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
    browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings, new CustomRequestContextHandler());
```

gives 2 errors :

- impossible to convert Cefsharp.RequestContextSettings to Cefsharp.IRequestContext
- CustomRequestContextHandler reference can't be found.

I used Nuget to include the package 71.0.2 targetFramework 461 to my project.

A RequestContext(requestContextSettings) constructor is working to run something, but the browser is frozen on the last page I loaded with the user1.

Some tips to fix the problem ?
I saw that a 73.1.120.pre is on GitHub, but I don't know how to manage that without some Nuget package.

Tx for your help.

Comment: RequestContextHandler is optional.

Comment: Also `73.1.120-pre01` is already on `Nuget.org`

Comment: Tx a lot for your updates. With 73.1.120-pre01 the program has always the same pbs. 2 errors if 2 parameters into the RequestContext constructor, and a screen frozen with the last page of the user1, if I use the RequestContext(requestContextSettings) constructor..

Comment: The compiler error is because you haven't implemented the handler. It's not a class provided by the framework,  it's one you implement. Screen frozen doesn't provide any meaningful technical details. Start by checking the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file